# how to find a variable is a type of array

Tags: php, arrays

How to find a variable is of type array in cakephp?

thanks

Comment: No offense, but typing the title in google with added keyword 'php' returns the correct answer as first result. I encourage filling up SO's knowledge-base, but this goes over the top IMO.

Comment: @Treb By answering these types of questions on SO we are grooming a new generation of programmers to ask questions first rather than perform simple research to find the answer. The whole give a fish / teach to fish proverb.

Comment: @Danied,Mike: As long as people are maintaining curiosity, they'll grow. When people just start giving up instead of asking questions, *then* bad things are happening.

Comment: @abales who said anything about giving up? The first thing one should do when they have a question is seek an answer themselves. Failing that, a question should be posed that not only answers the question but reveals in the flaw in the personal-research process. At what point does a person graduate from beginner to someone able enough to look at a manual?

Comment: @Mike B @Daniel - I could have added some whining about RTFM to my answer but I tire of reading such things. Also, if we are going to selectively reject RTFM questions based on what we like/dislike then we might as well do it across all tags (e.g. any HTML question on 'changing colour of blahblah', etc, or most HTML questions for that matter). This is way too unscientific, a good question to one person is a terrible question to another. If it is not a dupe, then it should be answered IMHO - otherwise we risk alienating would-be SOers who think SO is a community of arrogant 'obcenity here's

Comment: @karim I don't know where you and everyone else is saying that this question should not be answered at all, and the asker tared and feathered for all to see. All Daniel and I are trying to show is that this question could have been avoided by following these simple steps in the future. Why not kill two birds with one stone? I think it's pretty well accepted that you will learn/accomplish more in life if you don't have to ask a question every step along the way b/c you have the mental tools to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Use PHP's [`is_array`](http://www.php.net/is_array) function:

```
if(is_array($var)) {
    //do something
}
```